# Ubuntu Cordova TypeError: has no method exec in cordova-2.2.0.js at line 983

Tags: ubuntu, exec, cordova

Recently my laptop crashed and after I fixed it, I decided to switch to Ubuntu instead of Windows.
After setting up all the relevant things, so I can continue developing my android application with cordova I couldn't run the code which was working fine on the old setup with windows etc.

(Note: doesn't matter if I run the code on a VM or on a real device)

The problem is in that code snippet in a javascript file.

```
console.log("empty directory");
console.log(window.location);
console.log("location");

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(dirPath, function(fileEntry) 
{
    console.log("after resolveLocalFileSystem");
```

here is the error message.

```
   01-03 16:03:46.805: I/Web Console(18647): empty directory at file:///android_asset /www/update/update.js:145
   01-03 16:03:46.805: I/Web Console(18647): file:///android_asset/www/index.html at file:///android_asset/www/update/update.js:146
   01-03 16:03:46.805: I/Web Console(18647): location at file:///android_asset/www/update/update.js:147
   01-03 16:03:46.825: E/Web Console(18647): Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'exec' at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.2.0.js:983
```

As you can see, every console.log before window.resolve... works fine, but there is no "after resolveLocalFileSystem" log. Just the uncaught TypeError.

at the line 983 I found this

```
   var messages = nativeApiProvider.get().exec(service, action, callbackId, argsJson);
```

but the nativeApiProvider.get() is empty, so there really is no method exec.

I don't really know what to do now, because I literally found nothing concerning this problem in the internet and I don't know what might cause this.

thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you calling resolveLocalFileSystemURI after you get the "deviceready" event?

Comment: Yes I am. Im currently again developing with windows the project and it works fine, but not on ubuntu.
My guess is, that there are critical problems with the emulator. Not sure though why it isnt working on a real device.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald I am facing the same problem. Do you know what can be the issue?